# How to create a data set from a string based on patterns in R

Tags: r, string, dplyr, dataset

I have one string like this :

```
ST <- c("7.5 (wk0)  / 7.4 (wk4)  / 10.3 (wk8)  / 12.7 (wk12)",
        "140.0 (wk0)  / 161.3 (wk4)  / 142.5 (wk8)")
```

I want to generate a data set like below:

```
STvalue  WEEK
7.5        0
7.4        4
10.3       8
12.7       12
140.0      0
161.3      4
142.5      8
```

Answer (score 3):

All in base R:

```
strsplit(ST, "/") |>
  unlist() |>
  trimws() |>
  gsub(pattern = "[()wk]", replacement = "") |>
  strsplit(" ") |>
  do.call(what = rbind) |>
  as.data.frame() |>
  setNames(c("STvalue", "week")) |>
  type.convert()
#   STvalue week
# 1     7.5    0
# 2     7.4    4
# 3    10.3    8
# 4    12.7   12
# 5   140.0    0
# 6   161.3    4
# 7   142.5    8
```

Or with `library(tidyverse)`

```
library(tidyverse)
ST |> 
  str_split("/", simplify = FALSE) |>
  unlist() |>
  trimws() |>
  as_tibble() |>
  separate(value, into = c("STvalue", "week"), sep = " ") |>
  mutate(across(everything(), parse_number))
# # A tibble: 7 × 2
#   STvalue  week
#     <dbl> <dbl>
# 1     7.5     0
# 2     7.4     4
# 3    10.3     8
# 4    12.7    12
# 5   140       0
# 6   161.      4
# 7   142.      8
```

Answer (score 3):

**1) chartr/read.table** Replace w, k, ( and ) each with space and / with newline and then read that in with read.table.  No packages are used.

```
ST |>
  chartr(old = "wk()/", new = "    \n", x = _) |>
  read.table(text = _, col.names = c("STvalue", "WEEK"))

##   STvalue WEEK
## 1     7.5    0
## 2     7.4    4
## 3    10.3    8
## 4    12.7   12
## 5   140.0    0
## 6   161.3    4
## 7   142.5    8
```

**2) read_delim** We can do essentially the same thing with tidyverse.  This time we replace / with newline and then split on `wk(` regarding `)` as a comment character.

```
library(readr)
library(stringr)

ST |>
  str_replace_all("/", "\n") |>
  read_delim(delim = "(wk", comment = ")", col_names = c("STvalue", "WEEK"),
   col_types = "ni")

## # A tibble: 7 × 2
##   STvalue  WEEK
##     <dbl> <int>
## 1     7.5     0
## 2     7.4     4
## 3    10.3     8
## 4    12.7    12
## 5   140       0
## 6   161.      4
## 7   142.      8
```

**3) strcapture** Another base R approach is `strcapture`.  First split into lines and then match each line with the regular expression shown - `[0-9.]+` matches a substring of digits and decimal points and `\\D+` matches a substring of non-digits.  The capture groups (matches to portions within parentheses in the regular expression) are extracted and converted to the types indicated.

```
ST |>
  strsplit("/") |>
  unlist() |>
  strcapture("([0-9.]+)\\D+([0-9]+)", x = _,
    list(STvalue = numeric(0), WEEK = integer(0)))
```

**4) read.pattern** The gsubfn package has `read.pattern` which is similar to `strcapture` but it regards embedded newlines as new input lines so we can just replace each / with newline.  This uses the same regular expression as in (3).

```
library(gsubfn)
ST |>
  gsub("/", "\n", x = _) |>
  read.pattern(text = _, pattern = "([0-9.]+)\\D+([0-9]+)", 
    col.names = c("STvalue", "WEEK") )
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `tidyr` you can do this somewhat parsimoniously though `separate_longer_delim`,  `separate_wider_delim`, and `extract_numeric`:

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)

separate_longer_delim(data.frame(col = ST), col, delim = "/") %>%
  separate_wider_delim(col, delim = "(", names = c("STvalue", "Week")) %>%
  mutate(across(everything(), extract_numeric))
# or mutate(across(everything(), readr::parse_number))
```

Output:

```
  STvalue  Week
    <dbl> <dbl>
1     7.5     0
2     7.4     4
3    10.3     8
4    12.7    12
5   140       0
6   161.      4
7   142.      8
```

Comment: Very clean! I've never used the `_delim` variants before.

Comment: @GregorThomas Thanks! I just discovered their utility when coincidentally needing to do a very similar thing in my own work. Quite handy!